# While page loading in asp.net, stop running this script?

Tags: asp.net

I got the following error while runing my asp.net page 
stop runing this script?
A scrip on this page is causingyour browser to run slowly.If its continues to run,your computer might become unresponsive.

will you plz help me

Comment: Do you have any flash or javascript running on the page? If so, paste your source code into your question

Comment: Also try marking a few of your previous questions as answered. You'll be more likely to get answers that way.

Answer (score 0):

This will be caused by either some javascript (or flash as said above).
Have you got a continuous loop or are you just looping a lot of data?
Or calling a webservice via jQuery that is taking a long time to respond?